# Configuring custom year and generating dynamic query for filtering data in sql (Year from June to May)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

i have got a requirement to configure year in my project.
The user can define an year by there own, say from June to May or from April to March etc.
I am using MS SQL at the backend and now, i have to generate a dynamic sql query to check whether the given date is in " This Year " for filtering the data.

Following is a sample,

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE ([KEY] int , [DateValue] DateTime)

INSERT INTO @Sample ([KEY], [DateValue])  
            SELECT 1, '2017-01-16 11:14:39.683' 
UNION ALL   SELECT 2, '2017-06-16 11:14:39.683' 
UNION ALL   SELECT 3, '2017-08-16 11:14:39.683' 

-- If the year is defined as June to May then
-- Selecting DateValue for " This Year " should return rows 2 & 3 Only

--SELECT * FROM @Sample Where  [DateValue] = 'ThisYear'
```

-- I have done this -- but not working

```
Declare @startmonth int = 5

SELECT * FROM @Sample 
Where  [DateValue] BETWEEN 
DATEADD ( m, @startmonth - DATEPART(m,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETUTCDATE()),0)), DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETUTCDATE()),0))
AND  DATEADD(m,12, DATEADD ( m, @startmonth - DATEPART(m,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETUTCDATE()),0)), DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETUTCDATE()),0)))

-- **When @startmonth is greater than 6 , this query fails.**
```

Can anyone help ?
Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just do:

```
where year(dateadd(month, - @startmonth, datevalue)) = 'ThisYear'
```

This becomes a bit more complicated if you want to take advantage of an index on `datevalue`.  However, this is a place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the point. One more question..... How can we find 'ThisYear' value from the Configuration ?

Comment: You can get the current year doing `year(getdate())`.